# How to insert numbers into a cell without it changing to date in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to insert a value into my excel sheet and it keeps changing the string into a date. For example, I am trying to past 2-4 (One of the names for one Unit we use) and instead, I get February 4, 2020. Is there a way to prevent it from being changed?

```
x = 5
    For i = 1 To TheEnd - 1
        If IsEmpty(LANL(i, 1)) Then
            If Percent(i, 1) = 1 Then
                Cells(x, 1) = SU(i, 1)
                x = x + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i
```

Comment: `Cells(x, 1).NumberFormat = '@'` before assigning the value.

Comment: @ScottCraner Do I include the @ symbol or substitute it for something else

Comment: `'@'` is a shorthand for text.  so yes include it as it its typed.

Comment: @ScottCraner I am getting a syntax error when I use it

Comment: sorry, been writing queries in SQL: `Cells(x, 1).NumberFormat = "@"` should have used `"` instead of `'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we do something like:

```
Sub qwerty()
    With ActiveCell
        .Clear
        .NumberFormat = "@"
        .Value = "2-4"
        .ClearFormats
    End With
End Sub
```

Our result would be:

[image]